# Recommendation has an invalid ActionReference

Tags: visual-workflow, einstein-next-best-action

I am trying to build a Strategy Flow that dynamically creates Recommendation records for Cases. To be used by Next Best Action.

But when running the flow, I get the error "Recommendation has an invalid ActionReference". For the Action, you must specify the API name of the flow that gets called upon acceptance or rejection of a recommendation. The flow must be active.

I created a Recommendation record manually, then copy and pasted the value in ActionReference to my flow, but within quotes. To no avail, running the Strategy Flow keeps failing.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot with ActionReference and the two Labels, I noticed that the Values of the Labels did not have quotes. So I removed them from the Value of the ActionReference and that solved the problem!

Note that a Name field is mandatory when creating a Recommendation, so I had to add that as well, but my flow is now running.